# "For" loop in Python iterates over the same element twice - help would be most welcome

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

Essentially, I've created a very basic scraping code on Python (using Selenium), the main idea of which is to get data from a website. The key data are (i) model names of products (ii) their price and (iii) stock.

Due to the way the website is built, the only way to retrieve info about stock is to click on a button beneath a particular product which generates a small pop-up window and the info is then displayed on multiple lines, each line representing a particular warehouse.

All of this lengthy intro is just in case it is helpful by way of background, but the actual problem is as follows. For whatever reason, when I iterate over each line (i.e. warehouse) in the "stock" pop-up window, adding up the results (so that I have a single figure reflecting the total stock regardless of where it is warehoused), it would correctly calculate the total stock for "item 1" then it would use the result I got for "item 1" and use it for "item 2" as well (which is the problem) and then it proceeds to correctly calculate the stock figures for all subsequent items (c. 900 in total) except that each of them needs to be adjusted by one position (due to the incorrect result for item 2) - i.e. stock of "item 2" would show as "item 3" ... stock of "item 3" as "item 4" etc...

Below is the code I use (which might be totally wrong but it has worked for months until yesterday...)

Appreciate that it is likely to be diffuclt to help without seeing the rest of the code / structure of the website but i would nonetheless be extremely grateful if someone could kindly point if I am missing something very obvious or the snippet of the code is fundamentally flawed.

Any help would be most welcome!

```
stock_list =[]
stock_button=self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'XYZ') *### - the xpath is to locate the button underneath each product (per the intro above)*
for i in stock_button:
    i.click() *### - this pops-up the stock pop-up window *
    total_stock=0
    each_stock_line = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,stock_xpath)   ### each line = warehouse
    for i in each_stock_line:
        total_stock=total_stock+int(i.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    stock_list.append(total_stock)
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,x_button).click() ### this is to close the pop-up window
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious flaws, but there's not a lot to go on here. My guess is there's something unexpected in the HTM. Can you print/log each_stock_line to see if the first entry appears twice?

Comment: You really should use a different variable name for each of your two nested `for` loops, although that isn't actually causing a problem here.  My guess is that your xpath for `stock_button` is finding one unexpected element ahead of all the actual product items; you're getting the extra copy of product #1 basically by accident, then everything after that works just fine.  (This seems more likely than your suggestion that the problem is with product #2.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say definitively without seeing the actual website, but chances are you are seeing what you are seeing because the website is running JavaScript code to populate the pop-up window on click, and you need to add some wait command until the JavaScript finished updating the HTML before you start retrieving data.

If this is the case, chances are the website will also have an API, and rather than scraping the website's HTML with Selenium, it is likely it'll be much easier to scrape the underlying API instead.